# ERC 721 rental contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, dapps, erc-721

I am trying to write a contract for renting cars .
I have implemented the following 
addCar -> to add a new car to the lot
rentCar -> trasfers te ownership of the car to the rentee,and creates a rent object .

I want to use erc 721 tokens ,to represest each car .
How do I implement this ? For example should my mint function call the addCar function ? And I call the mint function from the UI ?

Comment: I did get around to finishing the application , just in case it might help someone out there https://github.com/kingpinXD/CarRental

Answer (score 1):

See this example https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721#usage at the ERC-721 reference implementation page.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";

/**
 * @dev This is an example contract implementation of NFToken with metadata extension.
 */
contract MyCarCollection is
  NFTokenMetadata,
  Ownable
{

  /**
   * @dev Contract constructor. Sets metadata extension `name` and `symbol`. 
   */
  constructor()
    public
  {
    nftName = "My Car Collection";
    nftSymbol = "MCC";
  }

  /**
   * @dev Mints a new NFT.
   * @param _to The address that will own the minted NFT.
   * @param _tokenId of the NFT to be minted by the msg.sender.
   * @param _uri String representing RFC 3986 URI.
   */
  function mint(
    address _to,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    string calldata _uri
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._mint(_to, _tokenId);
    super._setTokenUri(_tokenId, _uri);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Removes a NFT from owner.
   * @param _tokenId Which NFT we want to remove.
   */
  function burn(
    uint256 _tokenId
  )
    external
    onlyOwner
  {
    super._burn(_tokenId);
  }

}
```